# Get background of the element through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to alert the background of the LI element after clicking on it but the script doesn't work. What can be the problem?

```html
<li onclick="getVkPhotoUrl()" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/people)" class="block">
    </li>
<li onclick="getVkPhotoUrl()" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food)" class="block">
    </li>
<li onclick="getVkPhotoUrl()" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food)" class="block">
    </li>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function getVkPhotoUrl(){
  var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
        alert(bg);
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html is wrong. `li` elements must be contained in `ul`, `ol` or `menu` elements. Keep in mind in your example `this` refer to the global object(window). You can pass `this` to the function to refer to the DOM element. Also avoid inline javascript and css:

```js
$('ul li.block').on('click', function() {
  var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
  bg = bg.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
  console.log(bg);
});
```

```css
ul li.block.people {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/people);
}
ul li.block.food {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="block people"></li>
  <li class="block food"></li>
  <li class="block food"></li>
</ul>
```

**References**

[li element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

Answer (score 1):

change onclick as `onclick = yourMethodName(this)` and function as `yourMethodName(ctrl)` and in the method definition use `ctrl` instead of `this`.

```
<li onclick="getVkPhotoUrl(this)" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/people)" class="block">
</li>
<li onclick="getVkPhotoUrl(this)" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food)" class="block">
</li>
<li onclick="getVkPhotoUrl(this)" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food)" class="block">
</li>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getVkPhotoUrl(ctrl){
    var bg = $(ctrl).css('background-image');
    bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
    alert(bg);
}
</script>
```